# Calculate Schoenfeld residual for testing data?

Tags: survival, cox-model, schoenfeld-residuals

I am trying to get Schoenfeld residuals for testing data, using the model parameters obtained from training data. However in r, predict.coxph gives only the linear predictors and their exponentials. Could anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: All your suggestions are about getting Schoenfeld residuals for the current dataset, not the testing data. To do so for the testing data, you get the parameter, say, beta, and do`residual(coxph(..., data = testing, init = beta, control = coxph.control(iter.max)), type = "schoenfeld")`

Answer (score 2):

Use `cox.zph` from the `survival` package in the format of:

```
viol <- cox.zph(cox.model)
```

This will give you a table of hazard assumption test results (if significant, the coefficient is time-varying). You can plot the cox.zph to plot the Schoenfeld residuals, which looks something like:

```
plot(viol.cox)
```

[image]

Per coefficient.

Comment: thanks but not quite what I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Yuval nails it quite well.

If you want to get the exact (scaled) Schoenfeld residuals for **all covariates**, access them from the viol .zph object like that:

`viol$y`

and 
`viol$x` gives you the corresponding time steps that you would need to rebuild Yuval's plot from scratch.

Comment: Not what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get them out just using the residual function

```
residual( <coxmodel>  ,  type = "scaledsch")
```

Comment: Not what I was asking.